# Matlab- Create cell confusion matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array, confusion-matrix

I have the following cell matrix, which will be used as a confusion matrix:

```
confusion=cell(25,25);
```

Then, I have two other cell arrays, on which each line contains predicted labels (array output) and another cell matrix containing the real labels (array groundtruth).

```
whos output 

 Name             Size               Bytes  Class    Attributes

 output      702250x1             80943902  cell               

whos groundtruth                       
  Name                  Size               Bytes  Class    Attributes

  groundtruth      702250x1             84270000  cell
```

Then, I created the following script to create the confusion matrix

```
function confusion=write_confusion_matrix(predict, groundtruth)

   confusion=cell(25,25);

   for i=1:size(predict,1)
        confusion{groundtruth{i},predict{i}}=confusion{groundtruth{i}, predict{i}}+1;
   end
end
```

But when I run it in matlab I have the following error:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in write_confusion_matrix (line 4)
confusion{groundtruth{i},predict{i}}=confusion{groundtruth{i}, predict{i}}+1;
```

I was curious to print output's and groundtruth's values to see what was happening

```
 output{1}                                                                                                              

 ans =

 2

 groundtruth{1}                                                                                                         

 ans =

 1
```

So, nothing seems to be wrong with the values, so what is wrong here? is the confusion matrix's indexing right in the code?

Comment: You're only printing out the **first** value of both `output` and `groundtruth`.  At iteration `i` when the loop fails, `groundtruth{i}` or `predict{i}` is most likely bigger than 25.  In the Command Prompt, type in `dbstop if error`, run your code again then display what both `output` and `groundtruth` are at iteration `i`, then please update your post with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs in a `for` loop. Checking the first iteration of the loop is not sufficient in this case. `Index exceeds matrix dimensions` means there exists an `i` in the range of `1:size(output,1)` for which either `groundtruth{i}` or `output{i}` is greater than 25.

You can find out which one has at least one element bigger than the range:

```
% 0 means no, there is none above 25. 1 means yes, there exists at least one:
hasoutlier = any(cellfun(@(x) x > 25, groundtruth)) % similar for 'output'
```

Or you can count them:

```
outliercount = sum(cellfun(@(x) x > 25, groundtruth))
```

Maybe you also want to find these elements:

```
outlierindex = find(cellfun(@(x) x > 25, groundtruth))
```

By the way, I am wondering why are you working with cell arrays in this case? Why not numeric arrays?